# Problem with observers while engaging them with Uiapplication()

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, observers

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var check=UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification{


    didSet{

        print("print some thing")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


 }}
```

I run this code in my iPhone, when I enter background it is not executing the printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where is wrong**

Your code is in right way of declaring of any variable with a class type.

However, there is big mistake by creating the instance of `UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification` which is `class` type and is subclassed by `NSNotification.Name` which is a `struct`.

When you are accessing the `check` variable you can't set it because its non mutable struct means you can't mutate it (assigning value to it). So, the property observer `didSet` is not going to call, hence the print also not going call. This is the mistake.

**Solution:**

We can use `NotificationCenter` to observe the transitions of foreground to background and vice versa of the `iOS` application.

From Apple Doc.s

> Objects register with a notification center to receive notifications
>   (NSNotification objects) using the
>   addObserver(_:selector:name:object:) or
>   addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:) methods. When an object adds
>   itself as an observer, it specifies which notifications it should
>   receive. An object may therefore call this method several times in
>   order to register itself as an observer for several different
>   notifications.
>
> Each running app has a default notification center, and you can create
>   new notification centers to organize communications in particular
>   contexts.

Try this

**For Foreground**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc private func applicationDidEnterForeground() {

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

**For Background**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc private func applicationDidEnterBackground() {

    //Do your stuff here
}
```

For more, please visit

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter

Comment: My aim is not to observe the notification but to know what fault in my code?

Comment: @subhashchandru, please check the Edit (Where is wrong) for explanation.

Comment: yeah your answer is good but could you please bit elaborate the where is wrong part

Comment: yeah got it !! tanx for the answer!!

Comment: Glad to help you... :)